# Redisplay Stack Trace window

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I accidentally closed the Stack Trace window in the Visual Studio 2008 debugger.
How do I redisplay this window?

Comment: Can easily be found in the manual

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While debugging: Debug\Windows\Call stack

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

In Debug/Windows.